# sqlcmd hangs when started on powershell Ise

Tags: powershell-5.0, powershell-ise

I had sqlcmd  - Microsoft command line utility - working on Powershell Ise. After installation of SSMS 17 and newer odbc driver, it stopped working.
When I start it, it just hangs.

It does works on powershell console.
Do you have any suggestions on how to fix it?

I use powershell 5.1

Comment: hello Pimp Juice, thank you for your answer. it turned out that any pc where newest odbc version installed stops running sqlcmd from powershell Ise. it's still runs sqlcmd from powershell itself.

Comment: Okay, consider making that an answer and accepting it if it resolved the issue or explained what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that any pc where newest odbc version installed stops running sqlcmd from powershell Ise. it's still runs sqlcmd from powershell itself.